# Can i debug html page on run-time execution?

Tags: html, angularjs, debugging

I am working on HTML page and using angular js.
I Want to see how many records my database collection has in run-time.
Is there any way to trace it, like we debug Java class.

Comment: You can use developer tools in the browser to set break points and look at variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set break point by using Chrome dev tool.

1. Open Chrome Dev Tool (Press F12)
2. Click Sources Tab
3. Select your JS file from left panel
4. Click on the line no to set the breakpoint

Comment: Thanx a lot @NKDev

Answer (score 0):

No..I think it's not available like u want to see data.
But u can do debug through the browser by inspecting elements.and My suggestion is to write business logic in ur language (C#,java....)and make service.And consume from client side.There u can debug easily.
In client side usually, we get an error in syntax or library compatibility.

Comment: @ saktiprasad swain thanx for the suggestion, will surely do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug all your JavaScript code using developer tools in Chrome for example and its debug functionality.

IDE like VSCode has also a built-in functionality for debugging JavaScript code directly from the IDE for example.

Then if your question is to see live your database from the browser. Nope, you cannot do that. There is nothing related between a front-end application and the connected database directly from the browser.

Then maybe there are few chrome extensions which could allow you to connect to your db and see real time it. But this is not a built-in feature.

Comment: thanx a lot for your help